# My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments returns the wrong folder name in VB2008

Tags: vb.net

Coding in VB2008 with Net Framework 3.5 in Windows 7-32 bit.

The code:

```
TempUserPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
```

Returns the string `"C:\Users\Owner\Documents"` but that folder is actually named `"My Documents"` (i.e., is `"C:\Users\Owner\My Documents"` in the Finder).

When I try to create a new folder called `"Documents"` in the Owner directory, Windows asks if I want to merge its contents with the `My Documents` folder.  If I say yes, I am left with only the My Documents folder and none named `"Documents"`.

Thus when I attempt to read or write a file to the `TempUserPath` location, I get an `"access denied"` error.  This happens even after I manually change the name of the folder from `"My Documents"` to `"Documents"`.

Does anyone know why Windows seems to equate the filename `"Documents"` with `"My Documents"` within the VB environment and how I might work around this problem?

Comment: You are programming the machine now, not just using it.  You'll find out what it goes on under the hood, not merely what it looks like.  That directory on the disk *is* named "Documents".  Use cmd.exe to see what's really there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Documents & Documents in this case are the same. Use a different folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `My Documents` that you see doesn't really exist, it's a virtual folder that has the contents of the actual documents folder. You will also see the contents of the `Public Documents` folder of the user `Public` in your own documents folder.

The name of the actual physical folder where the files are stored is correctly returned by the code. You can move the location of that folder anywhere you like, so it could just as well be `D:\Birds\Pelicans` instead, but you would still see it as `My Documents` in your home directory.

If you get an access denied error when trying to read from the folder, your program simply doesn't have the proper permissions. It doesn't have anything to do with the virtual folder name.

Comment: Thanks to all for their suggestions but I think I need to use the my documents folder because I am writing programs for students to use on a university server.  Moreover this is a mature program that has been working fine running in XP with this code.  When I run it in Win 7 it gives me the errors reported.  So Win 7 handles this issue differently than XP.  The folder has full permissions set for the owner.

Comment: I just reran the same code in an XP machine and it returns the string "C:\Users\Owner\My Documents" and the files write properly to that folder.  So something is handled differently in Win 7 than in XP.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, works fine for me.

```
 Dim TempUserPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    IO.File.WriteAllText(IO.Path.Combine(TempUserPath, "TEST.txt"), "TEST")
```

You might try temporarily setting your mydocuments folder to everyone has full control to see if it's a permissions problem.